# Fetching Install locations of 64-bit software from registry when the script runs using 32-bit wscript/cscript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have both 64-bit and 32-bit java installed on my system at locations `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191` respectively.

I have the following code which fetches me the install location of a software on a system.

```
MsgBox fn_getInstallLocation("java")

function fn_getInstallLocation(strApplication)
    Dim strKey, objReg, subkey, arrKeys, strRequiredPath
    Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    strRequiredPath = ""
    strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"    '<----THIS KEY IS IMPORTANT
    set objReg = getObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")
    objReg.enumKey HKLM, strKey, arrKeys
    for each subkey in arrKeys
        objReg.getStringValue HKLM, strKey&subkey, "InstallLocation", strInstallLocation
        if InStr(1,strInstallLocation,strApplication,1)>0 Then
            strRequiredPath = strInstallLocation
            Exit for        
        End if
    next
    fn_getInstallLocation = strRequiredPath
End Function
```

**My Observations:**

1. On keeping the strKey value to `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and running the above script using 64-bit wscript, I get the expected output as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191`.
2. On changing the strKey value to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and running the script using 64-bit wscript, I get the expected output as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191`
3. On keeping the strKey value to `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` OR `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and running the above script using 32-bit wscript, I get the output as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191`(32-bit Java). **Is there a way to get the install location of 64-bit java when this script is executed using 32-bit mode?**

I am NOT playing around with different permutations and combinations. I am asking this because when I executed this script on a different machine, it did not give me proper results. The specifications of that machine are as follows:

```
OS: Windows 7 x64
Java: 64 bit(Not 32 bit) - In Registry Editor, it is present in the key - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
The script ran in 32 bit mode(cannot switch to 64-bit on that machine because I am running this script on a tool - TestComplete which runs in 32-bit mode on all machines. If I do decide to run Test complete in 64-bit mode, there will be architecture mismatch issues with ODBC drivers.)
```

Because the script ran using the 32-bit wscript, It could not return me the installation path of 64-bit JAVA. So, Is there any way I can make this solution to run in 32-bit mode and fetch the install location of 64-bit Softwares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the install location of 64 bit applications when the script is run in 32-bit host.

```
MsgBox fn_getInstallLocation("java")

function fn_getInstallLocation(strApplication)
    Dim strKey, objReg, subkey, arrKeys, strRequiredPath
    Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    strRequiredPath = ""
    strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"    '<----THIS KEY IS IMPORTANT

    Set oWbm = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
    oWbm.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", 64                '<----Change this parameter to 32 to get the install locations of 32-bit softwares
    Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oWbm).Get("StdRegProv")

    objReg.enumKey HKLM, strKey, arrKeys
    for each subkey in arrKeys
        objReg.getStringValue HKLM, strKey&subkey, "InstallLocation", strInstallLocation
        if InStr(1,strInstallLocation,strApplication,1)>0 Then
            strRequiredPath = strInstallLocation
            Exit for        
        End if
    next
    fn_getInstallLocation = strRequiredPath
End Function
```

This gave me the install location of the key which is present in the Registry Editor in the path `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and not from the path `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` despite running in 32 bit script host.

Reference for [`ConnectServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemlocator-connectserver) Method of [`SWbemLocator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemlocator) object.

Reference for [`SWbemNamedValueSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemnamedvalueset) and [`SWbemNamedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemnamedvalue)